# Why does electrocution stop after a few seconds in a bug zapper?

Tags: electricity

I have observed that when an insect is electrocuted in a bug zapper, there are typically a few sparks or flashes of light. Sometimes the insect will catch on flame in a tiny fire, and the body will burn for a few seconds before stopping burning. The lights and flames stop after a few seconds, but the insect body often, instead of falling, remains in position still connecting two wires.

Given that the body is still in position connecting two wires, why is it that after a few seconds, sparks or flashes of light stop appearing, and any fire is extinguished? Does that mean that electricity is no longer flowing through the insect's body, and if so, why does the electricity stop flowing if the body is still connecting the two wires?

Comment: They work by slowly charging capacitors up so that they dump a huge current across the bug. When you permanently connect the wires, as the bug being there does, the small current keeps flowing and the capacitors cannot charge up. No charge, no spark.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent  this would be true if the bug zapper is no longer working once a bug is caught this way. "seeking answers" is this true? the zapper zaps no more?

Answer (score 1):

An insect is electrically conductive only for so long as it contains water. The initial zap vaporizes the water, leaving fragments of chitonous exoskeletal remains that are insulators. The further flow of electricity is hence shut down after the bug blows up.

Note that in the case of an electric fence (which is by the way not designed to blow up a cow that touches it) the power supply runs on a duty cycle of about 1/10 of a second on, 9/10s of a second off, etc. so that if a tree branch shorts the wire to ground, the power supply will not overheat trying to feed high voltage to a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

As @naturallyIconsistent said a charge is built up between two wire grids and they it's equalised by the fly. For the charge to build up again they need be separated and then it can zap once more. Usually stationary zappers have a tray for catching the flies and the wire grid is standing vertically so all flies fall down.

If the fly remins in contact between the wires it will either conduct electricity between them, preventing them to build up charge or the zapper might have an internal mechanism for not charging up the wires if there is a current flowing. In the first scenario the electricity flowing through the dead fly would be nothing like the initial "zap".